# Python function correctly/incorrectly?

Tags: python, function

I'm just starting to use Python as a learning experience.  I know the basics logic of programming.  I have a function in python that is running every time I execute my program, even when it's not supposed to.  I used an if statement in the beginning of the function, but I don't know why this if statement isn't working.  I have another function that is similar and works correctly.  Am I missing something simple?

Here's the function that is not working...

```
def check_artist_art():
if os.path.exists("/tmp/artistinfo") and open("/tmp/artistinfo").read() != title:
#if artist == "":
    if os.path.exists(home + "/.artist"):
        os.remove(home + "/.artist")
    if os.path.exists("/tmp/artistinfo"):
        os.remove("/tmp/artistinfo")
        print artist
    return False
else:
    os.path.exists("/tmp/artistinfo") and open("/tmp/artistinfo").read() == artist
    return False
return True
```

And this is the similar function that is working correctly..

```
def check_album():
if os.path.exists("/tmp/albuminfo") and open("/tmp/albuminfo").read() != album:
    if os.path.exists(home + "/.album"):
        os.remove(home + "/.album")
    if os.path.exists("/tmp/albuminfo"):
        os.remove("/tmp/albuminfo")
    return False
elif os.path.exists("/tmp/trackinfo") and open("/tmp/trackinfo").read() == artist + album:
    return False
return True
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what "not working" means? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 3):

```
else:
    os.path.exists("/tmp/artistinfo") and open("/tmp/artistinfo").read() == artist
```

What are you expecting this to do?

Comment: If that file exists and it does not equal a variable that is defined earlier in the python script.

Answer (score 0):

First - what did you mean 'not working'?
Second - where artist, album and title variables are specified?
And third it looks like the following code:

```
else:
    os.path.exists("/tmp/artistinfo") and open("/tmp/artistinfo").read() == artist
```

need to be changed to:

```
elif os.path.exists("/tmp/artistinfo") and open("/tmp/artistinfo").read() == artist:
```

Comment: I'm sorry let met explain more. I use this python program to gather moc music info.  The variables artist, album, and title are defined earlier with mocp commands.  The code line you quoted was elif, I just changed it too see if it would make a difference and forgot too change it back before I posted here.

Comment: The function that I say is not working deletes/removes the files .artist and /tmp/artistinfo even if I manually create /tmp/artist with the current artist. The files .artist and /tmp/artist get created then removed a few seconds later.  Would it be more helpful if I posted the complete program?

Comment: @Anthony - all that i can suggest you is to add debug print statements before and after each if statement. This would defenitely help you to find a reason why files are not getting deleted.

Comment: I've added a simple print statement after the if statements in the problem function.  It's deleting files when it shouldn't.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I found the problem.  It was a simple problem causing a BIG headache.  I was using the wrong variable in test statement.  :(  It works great now with the correct variable.

Comment: ))) It is always something small that cause a BIG headache, that is why i am always using a lot of logging while trying to debug my code.